# Toggling of data not working with dynammic content using ajax in .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am making a  live data portal in which I have to display live data using Ajax in asp.net using c#.

I have one table and a div which contains data but in different way/different style.

Every time my page loads after 4 secs of time to show updated data i.e table and div both refreshes to have updated data.

Initially when page loads first time, I have displayed table to show data and hiden the data which is in div's form, if I clicked button(toggle button) it will display data in div's form and hide table data.

Now problem is that when I clicked toggle button it does not display's data in div form but it reloads whole java script
and display data in table every time when I clicked the button.
I want to toggle between table and a div.

Below I have my code what I have done so far.
Please help me what I have done wrong.
Thank You.

Note Data comes from db which is SQL.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
            <table id="liveData">
            </table>
            <div id="div_f" style="display:none;">
                <%--<table id="liveData_div"></table>--%>
            </div>
    </div>
    <button>Toggle Data</button>
</form>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    (function worker() {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "Default2.aspx/BindData",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("Hello");
                $("#liveData").empty();
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    InDivs(data);
                    $("#liveData").append("<tr><th>Node Id</th><th>Parent</th><th>Voltage</th><th>Humid</th><th>HumTemp</th><th>PrTemp</th><th>Pressure</th><th>Light</th><th>Accel_X</th><th>Accel_Y</th><th>result_time</th></tr>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#liveData").append("<tr><td>" +
                        data.d[i].nodeID + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].parent + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].voltage + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].humid + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].humtemp + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].prtemp + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].press + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].light + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].accel_x + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].accel_y + "</td><td>" +
                        data.d[i].result_time + "</td></tr>");
                    }


                }
                // Nontoggle();
            },

            error: function (result) {

                //Handling error
                alert("error");
            },
            complete: function () {
                // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                setTimeout(worker, 4000);
            }
        });
    })();

    function InDivs(data) {
        $("#div_f").empty();
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
            //$("#liveData").append("<tr><th>Node Id</th><th>Parent</th><th>Voltage</th><th>Humid</th><th>HumTemp</th><th>PrTemp</th><th>Pressure</th><th>Light</th><th>Accel_X</th><th>Accel_Y</th><th>result_time</th></tr>");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#div_f").append(
                "<table class='LiveData_div'><tr>" +
                "<td>Node Id</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].nodeID + "</td>" +
                "<td>Parent Id</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].parent + "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Voltage</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].voltage + "</td>" +
                "<td>Humid</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].humid + "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Hum Temp</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].humtemp + "</td>" +
                "<td>Press</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].press + "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Press Temp</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].prtemp + "</td>" +
                "<td>Light</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].light + "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Accel_x</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].accel_x + "</td>" +
                "<td>Accel_y</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].accel_y + "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Time</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].result_time + "</td>" +
                "</tr></table>");
            }
        }
    }
    $(function () {
        $('button').live('click', function () {
            $('#div_f').toggle();
            $('#liveData').toggle();
        });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Your page reload since the `button` tag has by default `type='submit'` and that will refresh the page.

**Solution**

You should define your type as `type='button'` to prevent that behavior, e.g :

```
<button type='button'>Toggle Data</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a "return false;" at the end of your click button:

```
    $('button').live('click', function () {
        $('#div_f').toggle();
        $('#liveData').toggle();
        return false;
    });
```